# Add code to admin bar only

Tags: admin-bar

I am trying to add a QR code to the bar and I can do this but it's my first time to make a WordPress plug-in and I'm having trouble. It ends up showing to everyone even if they are not an admin or even not logged in.

Any ideas or guidance would be very grateful.

```
function selfURL() {
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? ''
        : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s"
        : "";
    $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? ""
        : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
function strleft($s1, $s2) {
    return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2));
}

$urlToEncode=(selfURL());

generateQRwithGoogle($urlToEncode);
function generateQRwithGoogle($url,$widthHeight ='30',$EC_level='L',$margin='0') {
    $url = urlencode($url); 
    echo '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs='.$widthHeight.
'x'.$widthHeight.'&cht=qr&chld='.$EC_level.'|'.$margin.
'&chl='.$url.'" alt="QR code" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.
'" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.' "/>';
}
```

Comment: Also, I get an error upon activating: 

The plugin generated 371 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit to logged in users by wrapping the code with `is_logged_in()`.

You can limit to levels via `current_user_can('manage_options')`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one if statement:

```
if(is_admin()){
//your code here...
};
```

You can check out more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Actually this does not work for some reason.

Comment: Does not work as if it still shows to everyone?

About headers already ent error, delete all empty lines in the end of the file.